# how to pass header values like username and password in http:outbound-endpoint mule

Tags: mule

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
    <add-message-property key="username" value="admin" /> 
    <add-message-property key="password" value="admin"/>
    <add-message-property key="Accept" value="application/json"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<logger  message=" outbound header username and password... 
    #[message.outboundProperties['username']] and      
    #[message.outboundProperties['password']]"
 level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 

 <http:outbound-endpoint 
       exchange-pattern="request-response"  
       address="http://localhost:8080/callReservation" 
       method="POST" 
       contentType="application/json" 
       doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Here i'm unable to pass header values to http outbound endpoint.any suggestions

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8080/callreservation" method="POST" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP">
```

for this outbound endpoint , I try set username,password as headers

like follows

```
 <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
<add-message-property key="'http.headers'.username" value="admin"/> 
<add-message-property key="'http.headers'password" value="admin"/> 
</message-properties-transformer> 



<set-property propertyName="username" value="admin"/>
<set-property propertyName="password" value="isgn@123"/>
<set-property propertyName="Accept" value="application/json"/>
```

but nothing accept as headers for outbound endpoint . Im using mule 3.6.0

any suggestions

Comment: What mule version is that?

Comment: Also, what is the output of the logger?

Comment: I run application in anypoint studio. how to check mule version

Comment: In the project structure next to the Referenced Libraries and JRE System Library section you should also see a "Mule Server" with the version next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Mule 3.6.0, I suggest using a [HTTP Request element](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Request+Connector) since the HTTP Transport you are using is deprecated. Adding explicit headers with this connector is [easy](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Request+Connector#HTTPRequestConnector-Headers). Here's an example:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<flow>
...
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="callReservation" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
            <http:header headerName="username" value="admin"/>
            <http:header headerName="password" value="admin"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
...
</flow>
```

If you want to stick to the HTTP Transport then you need to use a [Properties Transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Property+Transformer+Reference). In this case:

```
<set-property propertyName="username" value="admin"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the username and password as follows :-

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  user="admin" password="admin" host="localhost" port="8080" path="callReservation" method="POST" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```